# XslCompiledTransform ignores DTD schema on .NET Framework 4.6 and above

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, .net-4.5

The target is to swap XML tags with keys (short vs full/ref tag names) specified in a DTD by running XSL transformation:

- the XSL determines which format an XML is: short or full
- the XSL tries to find opposite key (short for full, full for short) for the XML tags from the DTD
- the XSL replaces the XML tags with found opposite keys

so the XML

```
<!DOCTYPE Note SYSTEM "note.dtd">
<Note>
    <To>Tove</To>
    <From>Jani</From>
    <Heading>Reminder</Heading>
    <Body>Don't forget me this weekend</Body>
</Note>
```

becomes

```
<note>
    <x1>Tove</x1>
    <x2>Jani<x2/>
    <x3>Reminder</x3>
    <x4>Don't forget me this weekend</x4>
<note>
```

For this task the following DTD was used (only one replacement is specified to keep it representative)

```
<!ELEMENT Note (To,From,Heading,Body)>
<!ELEMENT To (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST To
  refname (To) #FIXED "To"
  shortname (to) #FIXED "x1">
<!ELEMENT From (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Heading (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Body (#PCDATA)>
```

the following XSL is being run

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
  <xsl:variable name="target">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="local-name(/*)='Note'">short</xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>reference</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="target-name">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="($target='short') and not(@shortname)">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$target='short'">
          <xsl:value-of select="@shortname"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="not(@refname)">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="@refname"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$target-name}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='refname' or name()='shortname')]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image: .NET Framework 4.6]
[image: .NET Framework 4.5]

It works perfectly in .NET Framework 4.5 (or MSBuild 14) and lower but once the code runs on a higher version then the replacement does not happen!
After few hours spent on this issue I could say that DTD is completely ignored in the higher versions: I put a wrong DTP path to the XML top intentionally:

- .NET Framework 4.5 and lower - expected error: `An error has occurred while opening external DTD 'file:///.../1note.dtd': Could not find file 'C:\...\1note.dtd'.`
- .NET Framework 4.6 and higher - no transformation, the input XML is returned.

I wrote the following C# code to demo this

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

using Xunit;

public class Tests
{
    private const string DtdDirectoryPath = @"c:\source\...\Resources";
    private const string DtdFileName = "note.dtd";

    private const string RootTag = "Note";
    private string xml = @"
<Note>
  <To>Tove</To>
  <From>Jani</From>
  <Heading>Reminder</Heading>
  <Body>Don't forget me this weekend</Body>
</Note>";

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // copy the DTD to the expected location
        var dtdFilePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, DtdFileName);
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(DtdDirectoryPath, DtdFileName), dtdFilePath, overwrite: true);

        XslCompiledTransform xslt;
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(Resources.SwitchTagNamesXSL))
        using (var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
        {
            xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(enableDebug: true);
            xslt.Load(xmlReader);
        }

        // add the DTD definition at the XML top in order the XSL transformation pass
        this.xml = this.xml.Insert(
            0,
            new XDocumentType(RootTag, publicId: null, systemId: DtdFileName, internalSubset: null).ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("Initial XML with DTD at the top");
        Console.WriteLine(this.xml);

        var output = new XDocument();
        using (var writer = output.CreateWriter())
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(this.xml))
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(
            stringReader,
            new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse })) // this flag is important to force DTD Processing
        {
            xslt.Transform(reader, writer);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Output");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Looks like the feature was lost somehow in latest .NET Framework, as workarounds I have been thinking to write custom code

- either script in XSL or
- do the transformation in C#

however I hope someone could know something about the misbehavior.

PS Before I got understating that the DTD is completely ignored I spent many hours googling the issue and made many experiments which did not happen:

- different test framework: XUnin, NUnit
- ran on different machines
- x64 x86
- enabled scripting in XslCompiledTransform
- set up different settings for XslCompiledTransform

Comment: @zx485 I am almost sure .NET does not support some features from modern XSL versions but the version number is for information mostly. I will update the version number in the example to 1.0.

Comment: Is your use case really loading the XML from a a string with a StringReader but expecting a relative URI in the string to be resolved? Or why that rather complex sample having a string with some XML, using string operation to prepend a DTD created with the XML LINQ? What happens if you just pull that `reader` through a while loop and examine each element node, does it have the fixed attributes from the DTD? Are the attributes really only lost when you pass the reader to XslCompiledTransform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your XmlReaderSettings need to explicitly define an `XmlResolver` with e.g.

```
new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver() }
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.xmlresolver?view=netframework-4.8:

> The default is a new XmlUrlResolver with no credentials. Starting with
>   the .NET Framework 4.5.2, this setting has a default value of null.

Comment: Yes, that is it! Thank you